# Types Library can't autoimport

Tags: typescript, npm

I have created a library that has only one export of an interface called IBasic.

I have published my library on npm and have installed it on another project.

When typing a const as IBasic I can't find the import with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> but if I go to the imports section and write the path by hand as `import { IBasic } from "node_modules/<libraryname>/src"` it works perfectly.

The question is: how to make my library interface works with auto import when installed in project?

library package.json

```
    {
      "name": "enzotypes",
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "description": "types library test",
      "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
      "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
      "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.6",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.51",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "rollup": "^4.9.6",
        "rollup-plugin-dts": "^6.1.0",
        "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "tslib": "^2.6.2",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0"
      }
    }
```

project package.json:

```
    {
        "name": "[...]",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "description": "",
        "author": "",
        "private": true,
        "license": "UNLICENSED",
        "scripts": {
            "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
            "build": "nest build",
            "gen:model": "ts-node src/commands/fromdbmodel.ts",
            "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
            "start": "nest start",
            "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
            "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
            "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
            "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
            "test": "jest --config jest.json",
            "test:watch": "jest --config jest.json --watch",
            "test:ci": "jest --config jest.json --ci --coverage --runInBand --testResultsProcessor='jest-junit'",
            "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
            "test:cov": "jest --config jest.json --coverage"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            [...]
            "enzotypes": "^1.0.1",
            [...]
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            [...]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't describe your code, post it. Especially the package.json files of both projects

Comment: Importing from `node_modules/...` seems strange

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a dual package (ie exporting ES6 and CommonJS modules). You should add an [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#writing-dual-packages-while-avoiding-or-minimizing-hazards) definition to the `package.json` of your `enzotypes` module do declare what exports to use when the consumer of that package uses CJS or ESM. We mostly do it like this

```
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "require": "./dist/index.js",
    "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  }
},
```

So all exports from `index.js` / `index.mjs` will be exported by the packge and you will be able to import everything you want by

```
import { IBasic } from "enzotypes"
```

Comment: I made it and nothing has changed, autoimport stills not working, here is my code: https://github.com/GuilhermeMaier/enzotypes.git